# c/c++ convert position dependent object to be position independent

Tags: c++, c, gcc, fpic

I have some compiled object file with debug symbols, but no acces to the sources.

Is there any method to convert this file to be position independent?

As far as I understand the '-fPIC' flag it makes all jumps to be relative. I'm wondering if having debug symbols is enough to be able to fix this jumps and so create a PIC binary.

If not please tell me why this operation is impossible to be done.

Comment: Your question seems to be compiler-specific, rather than a general C++ language question.  Please tag the question with the specific compiler, such as GCC, about which you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is rather platform than compiler specific since different platforms implement PIC code differently.

Nevertheless, I don't know of any platform where it would be possible with a simple tool to convert conventional code into position indepependant code. This is a decision that has to be made at compile/code generation time. Probably the only way to achieve your goal would be to disassemble the code and modify every absolute code/data reference into relative addressing.

The short answer would be: no, (practically) impossible.